# Writing a application that can use 2 Databases?

Tags: mysql, oracle, go

I'm trying to write a application in Go that is capable of connecting to oracle and MySQL based on a configuration. The issue I encountered now is when I used prepared statements. 
For example, consider the query below

```
Select * from data_table where id = 1
```

The corresponding prepared statement in MySQL and oracle is given below

```
MySQL -> Select * from data_table where id = ?
ORACLE -> Select * from data_table where id = :val1
```

If it is like this I have maintain 2 sets of queries and select the query based on the configuration. Is there a better way to do this?

I would like to avoid the hassle of keeping 2 sets of queries

Comment: Best practice, unless you are writing meta-SQL for a database-indepedent ORM tool, would be to maintain two separate sets of queries for each database.  So, what you are currently doing is already correct IMHO.

Comment: Maybe named arguments (https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NamedArg) can be used to have only one set of queries.

Comment: It's a pain in the backside but if you were writing an app that used two webservices, one that took XML and another that took JSON, that's what you'd have to support... (or write something that serialized your same data to XML or JSON)

Comment: Oracle also supports positional bind variables (`?`) so the MySQL code would work in Oracle as well in your example. There are other examples where you would need different syntax between the two database but if you limit the syntax to ANSI queries you *may* be able to only write queries that work on both.

Comment: My minority report: It is not opinion based. Actually, there is an idiomatic way to do it by using multiple implementations of an according interface.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Rephrase the question "I am trying to write an application in <generic language> that is capable of connecting to multiple databases....". The relevance of Go or the database languages is almost tangential to the question as a good answer should be able to port the methodology to any language or database. Casting aspersions on people's competence because they have not used a tag but have answered many questions on other tags the question includes is "not nice" and turn about could be done with some of the other tags in the question.

Comment: @MT0 Erm... It is not "tangential" relevance. In Java, for example, you would do this by actually providing according XML configs for Hibernate. And in "Oook!", you would need to implement your own driver. The question was tagged Go, there is a idiomatic way to do it in Go and hence it is _not_ opinion based. Hence, I pointed out that the people which put the question on hold prolly would have known this with experience in the the actual language. Which is NOT saying that they do not have competence - but might have not known that there IS an idiomatic way. Ad personam is your interpretation.

Comment: @ain Thanks for the suggestion it seems NamedArg does not work for MySQL got the error "driver does not support the use of Named Parameters"

Comment: @MT0 The question is focused on Go as I encountered this issue with go. I don't remeber facing this issue in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very much is by using interfaces.

Let‘s assume you create a web applications and you want to display users.

First, you‘d define an interface like

```golang
type Creator interface{
  Create(u User)(User,error)
}

type Reader interface{
  Read(k PrimaryKey)(User, error)
  ListAll()([]User,error)
  ListPaginated(page, offset int)([]User,error)
}

type Updater interface{
  Update(u User)(User, error)
  UpdateByKey(k PrimaryKey, u User)(User, error)
  UpdateMany(...User)error
}

type Deleter interface{
  Delete(u User)error
  DeleteMany(u ...User)error
  DeleteByKey(keys ...PrimaryKey)error
}

type CRUD interface {
  Creator
  Reader
  Updater
  Deleter
}
```

Next, implement the CRUD interface for each database type you want to support.

Now, you can create a handler:

```golang
// ListHandler uses an interface instead of a concrete type to
// retrieve the data from the databases.
// Not only does this approach make it possible to provide different
// implementations, but it makes unit testing way easier.
//
// "Thou Shalt Write Tests"
func ListHandler(rdr Reader) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        // Pagination ommited for brevity

        // Note that the handler is agnostic of the underlying implementation.
        u, err := rdr.ListAll()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("ListHandler: error retrieving user list: %s", err)
            // Do not do this in production! It might give an attacker information
            // Use a static error message instead!
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(u); err != nil {
            log.Printf("ListHandler: error encoding user list to JSON: %s", err)
            // See above
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    })
}
```

and set it up something like this:

```golang
func main() {
    // Get your config
    // Then simply use an implementation of CRUD

    var dbConn CRUD
    switch cfg.DbType {
    case "myql":
        // returns your implementation of CRUD using MySQL
        dbConn = createMySQLConnector(cfg)
    case "oracle":
        // returns your implementation of CRUD using Oracle
        dbConn = createOracleConnector(cfg)
    }

    http.Handle("/users/", ListHandler(dbConn))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8080", nil))
}
```

hth

Comment: You have addressed the connector issue and the structuring, but you have failed to answer my question about the query. The implementation of the CRUD will involve writing prepared statements for queries, Which would be different for each DB's I mentioned. Correct me I I'm wrong

Comment: @Manesh It is implicit. Your CRUD implementation would contain the queries needed.

Comment: I was looking for a solution where I could use the same query for both DB's. I was trying to avoid the hassle of keeping different sets of queries for the same purpose.

Comment: @Manesh You can not and you should not. Increments in oracle for example work _totally_ different than in MySQL. One way or the other, you need to either implement or use an abstraction layer. I showed you how to implement one. And there is https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/, but you should really think twice about using it, since it will come with [its own problems](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?utf8=✓&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+database%2Fsql+).